# Boolean operators in a switch statement?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to make this work with a switch, syntactically?

```
switch(i){
    case ('foo' || 'bar'):
        alert('foo or bar');
        break;
    default:
        alert('not foo or bar');
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
switch(i){
  case 'foo':
  case 'bar':
    alert('foo or bar');
    break;
  case 'other':
  default:
    alert('other');
}
```

Note: "other" isn't required, I'm just showing that you can stack cases with default as well.

Answer (score 5):

From the **[official Mozilla Developer Center docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/switch)**, use multiple cases like so:

```
 // multiple cases:      

   case "Mangoes":  
   case "Papayas":  
      document.write("Mangoes and papayas are $2.79 a pound.<br>");  
      break;  
   default:  
      document.write("Sorry, we are out of " + expr + ".<br>");  
 }
```

Or if looking for an IE solution you would use the **[JScript docs for switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wzh7bhy(VS.80).aspx)** which refer to case conditions as "labels" and states:

> multiple label blocks are executed if a
>   break statement is not used.

Effectively both sets of documentation say the same thing about putting multiple cases together.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't work that way. Do it like this:

```
switch(i){
    case 'foo':
    case 'bar':
        alert('foo or bar');
        break;
    default:
        alert('not foo or bar');
}
```

Like in C, JavaScript's `case` clause will cascade.

Comment: Duh! Thanks. I don't know how I didn't think of that. 

edit - thanks everyone! Sorry that I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your example is that the expression `('foo' || 'bar')` evaluates to `'foo'`, and therefore it will only match when `i` is `'foo'`, and never when `i` is `'bar'`.

The `||` operator produces the value of its first operand if the first operand is truthy. Otherwise it produces the value of the second operand. A non-empty string is always truthy, and that's why your expression is returning `'foo'`.

However, in JavaScript each `case` falls through into the next case unless you explicitly disrupt the flow with a `break` or a `return`. Therefore you can easily make it work as follows:

```
switch(i) {
    case 'foo':
    case 'bar':
        alert('foo or bar');
        break;
    default:
        alert('not foo or bar');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(i){
    case 'foo':
    case 'bar':
        alert('foo or bar');
        break;
    default:
        alert('not foo or bar');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something along this line work?

```
switch(i){ 
    case ('foo'):
    case ('bar'): 
        alert('foo or bar'); 
        break; 
    default: 
        alert('not foo or bar'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
switch(i)
{
    case 'foo':
    case 'bar':
        alert('foo or bar');
        break;
    default:
        alert('not foo or bar');
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set separate cases for each value.

```
switch(i)
{ 
    case 'foo': 
    case 'bar': 
        alert('foo or bar'); 
        break; 
    default: 
        alert('not foo or bar'); 
}
```

Using your code, you'll only get the alert if `i` evaluates to true, since a string that is not empty also evaluates to true.